# Checking multiple conditions in PHP 'if' statement

Tags: php, opencart

```
if($this->request->get['product_id'] == (53 || 52 || 43)){
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product2.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product2.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/product/product2.tpl';
    }
} else{
    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/product/product.tpl';
    }
}
```

I wanna achieve it that if product id is `53` or `50` or `43` then...the same thing..but i am not sure its correct like this

Comment: it was, because it caught attention in one second :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can store the product IDs in array then use the [`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) function:

```
if (in_array($this->request->get['product_id'], array (53, 52, 43))) {
```

> `in_array` - Checks if a value exists in an array

Comment: This is the best solution, @Tom should stick with this one.

Comment: somehow it doesnt seem to work this one :S i changed it exactly and it shows error

Comment: it works now, extra ) needed in the end, thank you for all :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($this->request->get['product_id'] == (53 || 52 || 43)){
```

Should be:

```
if($this->request->get['product_id'] == 53
   || $this->request->get['product_id'] == 52
   || $this->request->get['product_id'] == 43) {
```

You could also use `in_array` which would make your code look cleaner, but may be slower. Tim Cooper has given example code for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$prodId = $this->request->get['product_id'];
if($prodId == 53 || $prodId == 52 || $prodId == 43){
....
```